# Can we add a "please tag your system" on-hold message?

Tags: feature-request, tags, close-reasons, game-systems, new-users

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157583/longbows-and-extra-attacks-for-5th-level-fighters) has a common problem where a new user is unfamiliar with the requirement to tag questions with the correct rules system (e.g. [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)). The question was put on hold, but with the generic "unclear what you're asking" message:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

This resulted in the user adding a comment with additional information to clarify the specific problem, but the hold message did not address the real issue, which was the missing system tag. Another user gave the traditional welcome message comment and included the system-request, but the asker evidently did not notice the exhortation to tag the correct system (I suspect these sometimes get lost in the generic welcome message text, which is why I prefer to ask directly).

Is it technically possible on RPG.SE to use a custom hold message for the user case of "please tag your system"?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Could we have a separate close reason for missing system tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7333/52137)

Comment: We're limited to three custom close messages?  Why, are they stored in bits made out of superconducting platinum?