# Get the SE system to enforce system tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, game-systems

I'm new here, but I've already picked up that Standard Policy is to tag questions with the system that you're playing in, and that the vast majority of questions can be closed a "Lacking details" if the system isn't specified.

There's also a [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) and a [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) tag that would cover the overwhelming majority of what's left.

Would there be some way to teach SE that "these system tags are special, and all questions must have one"? Meta-SEs already have that for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and [support](/questions/tagged/support). Can that system be re-purposed for this goal?

---

(If necessary, we could add a [specific-obscure-rules-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-obscure-rules-system) tag, to cover the remaining tiny number of questions with no suitable tags - if such even exist.)

Comment: Related: "[Can/should we include the system tag requirement in our tour?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10015)" and "[New ask page: How do we want to use it to help new users specify their system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9822)" and "[Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and more meaningful](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8702)" and "[Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8366)"

Comment: And "[Could we have a separate close reason for missing system tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7333)" and "[Can the system tag policy be stated to askers in advance](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9985)" and "[Make a special tag class for "game tags".](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1651)"

Comment: Related: [specifically proposed and decided against](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7686/1204) in response to [Can our tag-prompt nudge toward including system?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7681/1204) in 2018. Since I'm also against this feature I'll be downvoting this meta. I'm also rephrasing the title to a request, since it's a feature request, so that it does not appear to be merely a question.

Comment: As of February 2021, less than two months before this question was asked, SE staff declined to add any support for the sort of tag coloring or classification that would make this feature possible. Voting to close as a duplicate.